# How can I Validate numbers in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have this validation

http://jsbin.com/dafukewa/1

it validates only numbers 0 to 10 ,it works with the jquery event keyup ,I want to know if there is a way to do it but at the time of the writing and change quickly of input ,delete all the text different of 0 to 10 .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: So you want a textfield that's only numbers?

Comment: yes I want the number validation and I have it the problem is when i clicked in another input at the same time of writing ,the validation is not working in this situation,could you help me please?

Comment: `/^[0-9]$/.match(Element);` for integers, floating point gets a bit more tricky.

Comment: but i just want the 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10 not all the whole numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `event.which` to get the key pressed and try to filter out non-numbers based on that.

Example:

```
$('input#text').keypress(function (event){
  if (!(event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57)){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Answer (score 0):

now it's faster than you. why are you empty textbox after condition instead you allow value if condition is true otherwise keep textbox empty.

```
$('.calificacion').keyup(function (event) {
    var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    $(this).val('');
    if (typeof num === "number" && num < 11 && num > -1) {
        $(this).val(num);
    }
});
```

see jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav22031987/q6b52L3t/